# Is there a way to look up by index value without handling errors?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
               pmid
id                                                        
NCT02835976    NaN
NCT02835885    1235
NCT02835560    1270
NCT02835118    NaN
```

Now I want to find the row that matches a particular key. I can do `df.loc(x)` but I get an error if the ID is not in the index:

```
KeyError: u'the label [NCT01001741] is not in the [index]'
```

Do I really need to write error-handling code? Is there any method in pandas that will simply return `None` if the key is not in the index?

[The docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-label) seem to suggest that `ix` will do this, but also that `ix` is generally to be avoided.

Comment: `df.get(x)` isn't it basically a dictionary?

Comment: @M.Klugerford that just seems to return `None`, even for rows that should have a result.

Comment: Right .. `df.get()` gets columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like following:

```
df[df.index == 'NCT01001741']
```

This will return no error